# NullPointerException with zxing library for QR scanning (android app Xamarin Froms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing, barcode-scanner

The zxing QR code reader gives crash with  **Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference'**  below are the code which i added.

```
        {
            try
            {
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

                base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
// and 
 try
            {
                ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);

                ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
 // on the on create 

// button click 

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
                if (_scanPage != null)
                {
                    _scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                    {
                        _scanPage.IsScanning = false;

                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            Navigation.PopAsync();
                            DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                        });
                    };
                }

                await Navigation.PushAsync(_scanPage).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

The Plugin Details are below

**ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.4.1** and **ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.4.1**

please suggest me is there is any other plugin which we can use instead

Comment: Did you try set IsScanning true on OnAppearing?

Comment: @sermet yes i have added that also. i added in xaml and set the isScaning as true still am getting the same issue. as you can see the code, i have added on other way too. on the button click i have created new instance

Comment: @sermet this is the code in Xaml 
<zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="BarcodeScanView" IsScanning="True" IsVisible="True" HeightRequest="200"   />

Comment: I have created a new solution and tried to implement the same. it works fine. what can be the issue in my solution. am using mvvmcross  
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference'

Comment: I write a small sample http://www.filedropper.com/zxingandroidsample

Comment: @sermet i have created new app and it works fine. where as in my mvvmcross solution its not working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 updated the Initialize scanner code in Main Activity, below are the code 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            //-->Initialize scanner
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(this.Application);
```

and it work fine now

Comment: You can mark it as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error for Android in my Xamarin Forms - MvvmCross project. The solution for me was to add

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle); //not needed for MvvmCross
```

in MainActivity. Now MainActivity OnCreate results

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);  //ZXing needs it
    ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
}
```